# Slovenian stemmer for Sphinx

Tags: php, search, full-text-search, sphinx, stemming

I am searching stemming algorithm for Slovenian language that I can use with Sphinx search.

What I'm trying to achieve is for example when searching for 'jabolka', I also want results for documents containing 'jabolko', 'jabolki', 'jabolk', etc.

I found some references about existence of Slovenian stemmer, but I can't find where to download it, it's not even for sale anywhere...

Another option I've came across is using option `wordforms` in Sphinx source config (http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#conf-wordforms), but building my own dictionary would be too difficult, so I'm wondering are there any publicly accessible dictionaries available already?

---

In case Slovenian stemmer is not available, can somebody suggest some other approach of achieving similar search results?

Comment: I have found Slovenian stemmer at [tartarus snowball mail archive](http://snowball.tartarus.org/archives/snowball-discuss/0725.html). It is in snowball format, but it seems incomplete. Also I don't know how to use it with Sphinx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to compile slovenian stemmer in following steps:

1. Download http://snowball.tartarus.org/dist/snowball_code.tgz (source code for snowball) and unpack it
2. Download slovenian algorithm from http://snowball.tartarus.org/archives/snowball-discuss/0725.html and save it to unpacked project from step 1 in folder /algorithms/slovene. Name of the file has to be `stem_ISO_8859_2.sbl`
3. Algorithm is in ISO encoding, so I converted it to UTF8 and saved it as `stem_Unicode.sbl` (you have to find utf char codes for slovenian special chars like ČŠŽĆ)
4. Edit both of .txt files in /libstemmer folder and add entries for slovenian:

   ```
   slovene         UTF_8,ISO_8859_2        slovene,sl,slv
   ```
5. Edit /GNUmakefile and add slovene (once to list of languages for utf and once for ISO_8859_2_algorithms)
6. go to folder /libstemmer and run:

   ```
   ./mkmodules.pl modules.h src_c modules.txt ../mkinc.mak
   ./mkmodules.pl modules_utf8.h src_c  modules_utf8.txt ../mkinc_utf8.mak
   ```

   This will generate files needed for compiling later.
7. run `make` (from root of unpacked files)
8. If there were no errors during compile you should have /src_c folder and code for slovenian stemmer in them (next to others)

   ```
   stem_UTF_8_slovene.c
   stem_ISO_8859_2_slovene.c
   ...
   ```
9. Unpack latest sphinx and copy all files from your snowball project to sphinx /libstemmer_c folder (excluding `libstemmer.o` and `GNUmakefile`)
10. compile sphinx:

    ```
    touch NEWS README AUTHORS ChangeLog
    autoreconf --force --install
    ./configure --with-libstemmer
    make
    make install
    ```
11. if all went fine you should have slovene stemmer for sphinx working, you just have to enable it in you sphinx index configuratiun (on my Debian it is in /usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf):

    ```
    charset_type = utf-8
    morphology = libstemmer_slovene
    ```

Hope this helps someone, I had no prior experience with **autoconf** so it took me a while to figure this out.

This slovene stemmer is not officially released on http://snowball.tartarus.org, but from my tests it works good enough for my project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will do what you want, but I came across this reference to a tool called **[spelldump](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#ref-spelldump)**  in the Sphinx documentation:

> spelldump is one of the helper tools within the Sphinx package.
>
> It is used to extract the contents of a dictionary file that uses
> ispell or MySpell format, which can help build word lists for
> wordforms - all of the possible forms are pre-built for you.
>
> http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#ref-spelldump

It requires "a dictionary file that uses ispell or MySpell" - I found [a reference to a Slovenian ispell dictionary file](http://lasr.cs.ucla.edu/geoff/ispell-dictionaries.html#Slovenian-dicts), which might be suitable.

Comment: all links to resources on the provided link are dead

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying to find a stemmer for the Slovene language but didn't come across any existing solutions.

I've built my own stemmer in Ruby using the never implemented [Snowball](http://snowball.tartarus.org/archives/snowball-discuss/0725.html) version as inspiration.

It's available on Github as [hajkr/slovene-stemmer](https://github.com/Hajkr/slovene-stemmer). It's far from perfect, but it works for most cases.