# Adding language to pystemmer

Tags: python, stemming, snowball

I would like to use [`pystemmer`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyStemmer/1.0.1) with [`whoosh`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Whoosh/), but there is no support for my language.

I found two snowball files for my language ([Snowball](http://snowball.tartarus.org/)), and i made *.c files from them as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714040/slovenian-stemmer-for-sphinx.).

Now i would like to include *.c files in pystemmer. I added them to source, iI edited all the files where I've found link/list of language files, but after installing pystemmer (from source) I still can't use my language - it is not on the list `Stemmer.algorithms()`.

What am I doing wrong?