# How to use new .sbl Snowball algorithm in Python?

Tags: python, stemming, snowball

I want to use Lithuanian language stemmer in Python, however, there is no Lithuanian language in common tools like [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html).

However, I could find snowball .sbl files of Lithuanian stemmers [here](https://github.com/dainiusjocas/snowball/blob/master/algorithms/lithuanian/stem_ISO_8859_1.sbl) and [here](https://github.com/tokenmill/snowball/blob/master/lithuanian.sbl).

But how to use them in **Python**?

What I was able to [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714040/slovenian-stemmer-for-sphinx) is command line approach to get .c files. But what next?

As is stated in snowball official [page](http://snowballstem.org/download.html), there is PyStemmer - a Python interface for snowball. But there I could not find any way to use new or custom .sbl algorithms.

So how to get new .sbl algorithm to Python?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, Lithuanian language was added to Snowball git [repo](https://github.com/snowballstem/snowball), but pyStemmer uses an old version of that repo which doesn't contain it. I didn't manage to install new version of Snowball in python correctly, but instead used c executable with python subprocess module.

For that you just need to clone the repository, install it with command `make` and then you get stemwords executable. You could test the Lithuanian language with it using command in unix terminal `./stemwords -l lt` and then enter words the words you would like to be processed.

Using it with python's subprocess for process files which contain words to be stemmed line by line:

```
import subprocess
args = ("./stemwords", "-l", "lt", "-i", "input_file.txt", "-o", "output_file.txt")
popen = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
popen.wait()
```

input file:

```
Kodėl
moteriai
vienišai
ištekėjusiai
```

output file:

```
kod
mot
vieniš
ištekėjus
```

Comment: How to install it on windows? [link] https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/ `make` on windows throws an error: ```The system cannot find the path specified.
GNUmakefile:48: algorithms.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `algorithms.mk'.  Stop.```